# How to Assign SQLPLUS output value to Variable from root

Tags: bash, shell-script, sqlplus

I am trying to assign sqlplus output to unix variable as a root user using the following function

```
function sql {
su - oracle -c "
 export ORACLE_HOME=$( "`grep "OraG" /u01/app/oraInventory/ContentsXML/inventory.xml | awk '{print $3}'|  cut -d= -f2 | sed 's/\"//g'`"/bin/crsctl status resource -w "((TYPE = ora.database.type) AND (LAST_SERVER = $(hostname -s)))" -f | grep ^ORACLE_HOME= | awk -F= '{ print $2 }' )

   export ORACLE_SID=$( "`grep "OraG" /u01/app/oraInventory/ContentsXML/inventory.xml | awk '{print $3}'|  cut -d= -f2 | sed 's/\"//g'`"/bin/crsctl status resource -w "((TYPE = ora.database.type) AND (LAST_SERVER = $(hostname -s)))" -f | grep ^USR_ORA_INST_NAME= | awk -F= '{ print $2 }' )

   export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

   SQL_OUTPUT=$( $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s / as sysdba<< OCI2
   connect / as sysdba
   set heading off
   set feedback off
   set linesize 145
   set linesize 145
   set feedback off
   spool /tmp/sqlplus.log
   $1
   spool off
   exit
OCI2
   )
   echo "$SQL_OUTPUT"| grep -v \^$
"
}

SPFILE=$(sql "select value from v\$parameter where name = 'spfile';")
```

but getting the following error

```
[root@xxxxxx tmp]# SPFILE=$(sql "select value from v\$parameter where name = 'spfile';")
-bash: /bin/sqlplus: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your `ORACLE_HOME` variable is not being set or being set to a NULL value and therefore it is looking for the `sqlplus` binary in `/bin/sqlplus` where it does not exist.

Comment: given that you're calling `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus` and the error is reporting `bash: /bin/sqlplus: No such file or directory`, it seems to follow that `$ORACLE_HOME` is not getting set; can you confirm the inner commands of `export ORACLE_HOME...`?

Comment: tried to echo $ORACE_HOME.$ORACLE_SID, but no luck..any idea how to confirm inner export output?